# Adding second HP Smart array P420i 0.5GB cache increase speed?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm novice with servers, and I apologize for perhaps asking an easy question.

I have an HP Proliant ML350p Gen8 server with smart array p420i 500mg Cache.

the server has:
2 logical SSD drives in Raid 1 configuration
vmWare software
virtual machines are Windows 2012R   Running Databases.

I still notice a delay in processing information both read and write.

Question:  Will adding another Smart Array with higher GB cache allow for more open channels and therefore better performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With such a small number of disks (2), adding an additional controller will buy you **nothing** at all.

Rather, your SSD can be slowed by disabled DRAM private cache. In short, RAID controller often disables the disk's internal cache. This is done *on purpose*, to guarantee maximum affidability from disks whose caches are not power-protected.

However, *for testing only*, you can re-enable the disk's internal cache. The precise steps to re-enable it is controller dependant, so you have to check on the manual.

Remember that letting disks run for extended period with their internal cache enabled can cause data loss in the case of power failure.

Comment: Shodanshok, thank you for the response.  I wrote the Array wrong.  I have 2 logical volumes each with 2 physical ssd discs.  and two more logical volumes with 2 HDD discs. Total 4 volumes (8 discs).  Will this make any difference?

Comment: Is it possible that lag delay can be caused by network congestion? I have modem with 100Mb/sec duplex, but all other wires are 1Gb speed.     I will check on testing with Re-enabled disks internal cache.  Thank you

Comment: 8 disks remains firmly on the possibilities of a single controller setup. 100 mb/s network connection can easily become a bottleneck, but without further clarifications is not possible to identify your problem.